# How to find unnecessary deepcopys in python?

Tags: python, optimization, code-analysis, deep-copy

I'm for the first time working on a rather large python project and I noticed that I used a lot of deepcopys, probably more than I should.

I'm wondering if there is a code analysis tool/method that lets me find obvious unnecessary calls to deepcopy. For example if the result of a deepcopy is only read from and never changed, in which case just passing the original object would have been fine.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool, but be aware that "passing the original object" might *not always* be fine.  `b = deepcopy(a)`, will decouple `a` from `b` in *both* directions.  Without deep copying, not only will changes in members of  `b` affect `a` (as you note), but changes in members of the "original object" `a` will affect the copy `b`.  Just a heads up.

Comment: Define "unnecessary" - then it'll be more clear what to look for.

Comment: That said, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. If you wish to "optimize" the code "just because", you're setting yourself up for failure. You'll waste your time 'cuz you cannot really optimize something without knowing what the optimum is. And you sound like you don't understand the code's workings - so you'll probably break it big time while at it, too.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Well what I meant by optimize is to reduce runtime, since unncecessarily copying objects takes time. jedwards is correct in pointing out a mistake in my question, however, if you don't edit either b or a, and both objects are only read from, the deepcopy is unnecessary.
I do believe that it should be possible to detect such cases over a given run of a program and was thus asking if such a program exists.

Comment: Even if `a` is not altered during a specific run of the program, you cannot be sure it wouldn't be in another scenario. Since Python allows to alter (almost) any object in any way, such a scenario always exists, and the question rather is whether it's a supported use case under your API.

Answer (score 1):

Such a tool doesn't and cannot exist until you give an objective definition to "(obvious) unnecessary calls to `deepcopy`".

E.g. the example you've given is plain wrong. If you read the original object instead of a deepcopy and that object is mutated, you'll be getting the new data when reading it instead of what it held at the moment the copy was made.